Ulimits ignored on openSUSE
I'm on openSUSE Leap 15.6 x86_64, kernel 6.4.0-150600.23.25-default. My open files software ulimit is set to very low 1024. While this was never big issue on Debian based systems I have hard time figuring out OpenSUSE way to increase it permanently.
ulimit -Sn 10240
changes it temporarily and I could enter it probably somewhere bashrc but I would like more clean way.
I'm wondering why this doesn't work:
/etc/security/limits.conf:
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#
*               soft    nofile          65535
#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20

The /etc/sysctl.conf as well as /etc/sysctl.d/ are all commented.
The /etc/pam.d/login contains:
session   include    common-session
and /etc/pam.d/common-session contains:
session required        pam_limits.so  
Despite that limits are not applied per my configuration or overridden somewhere else. Hardware limit is 524288 so bigger than above 65535
Also:
 cat /proc/1/cmdline 
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd--switched-root--system--deserialize=32(base) n


Changing limits.conf has no effect on existing sessions.  Make sure you are checking in a new session.

Yes I did. In fact that's one od the reason its hard to debug as I could change it multiple places but this would require same number of restarts.So now I'm looking for smart way to step by step check how OS determines current value. It could be that its compiled in kernel because grepping arround for 1024 returns nothing. But I woule like to chęci how OS initializes it exacly and why it ignores one of the files which was there by default with the line I only uncommented and set own value.

Also note that this is a soft limit and the application itself can change it!  (per process)

Thanks but again, this is not my issue. The only problem I have is to do permanently what works temporarily.
